# make class static property observable in mobx-6

Tags: javascript, mobx, mobx-react, state-management

here's my code:

```
export default class ViewStore {
    templateName = '';
    static views = [];
    constructor(mainStore: MainStore) {
        makeObservable(this, {
            templateName: observable,
            ViewStore.views: observable,
        });
    }
}
```

I want to define views as observable. I've tried referring to it by `this. views` and `views` but none of them worked either.

in mobX5 it was possible by defining @observable before views when defining it like this:

```
@observable static views = [];
```

but I don't know how to achieve this in mobX 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the same way as you did with MobX@5, but without decorator api:

```
import { observable } from "mobx";


export default class ViewStore {
    templateName = '';
    // Call observable as a function
    static views = observable([]);
    constructor(mainStore: MainStore) {
        makeObservable(this, {
            templateName: observable,
            // No need this line
            // ViewStore.views: observable,
        });
    }
}
```